# HTML form with 2 (hidden) submit buttons and 1 other hidden input

Tags: php, javascript, html, submit, hidden

I'm trying to build this application that runs on Android tablets with barcode scanners attached.
The barcode scanners send an Enter after each scanned code.

I need to scan 2 barcodes and submit the form.

I created a form with two sets of input + submit button, the second one hidden. After the first barcode is scanned and the scnner send the Enter key, the hidden elements are revealed and I can scan the second barcode. However, the second time the Enter key doesn't work. It only work if I push the button (after I unhide it).
How can I take care of this so it will not need user input (other than scanning barcodes)?

Here's my code so far:

```
    <form action="barcode.php" method="post" class="pure-form" style="width:100%">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Scaneaza o fisa noua de <?php echo $operation; ?>:</legend>
            <input type="text" name="barcode" autofocus id="InputID" placeholder="Codul de bare" style="width:100%;font-size:2em">
            <button style="width:0;visibility:hidden;" type="submit" onclick="show_popup('my_popup'); return false;"></button>
                <div id="my_popup" style="display:none;border:3px dotted gray;padding:.3em;background-color:white;position:absolute;width:80%;height:20%;margin:-50px 50px 0 50px;">
                    <legend>Introdu numarul de KO-uri:</legend>
                    <input type="text" name="kos" autofocus id="InputID" placeholder="KO-uri" style="width:100%;font-size:2em">
                    <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary" style="/*width:0;visibility:hidden;*/" onclick="hide_popup('my_popup'); return true;">Trimite</button>
                </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function FocusOnInput() { document.getElementById("InputID").focus(); }
        function show_popup(id) {
            if (document.getElementById){
                obj = document.getElementById(id);
                if (obj.style.display == "none") {
                    obj.style.display = "";
                }
            }
        }
        function hide_popup(id){
            if (document.getElementById){
                obj = document.getElementById(id);
                if (obj.style.display == ""){
                    obj.style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

And the barcode.php file:

```
    <?php
    ob_start();
    mysql_connect ("localhost","root","root") or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db ("eficacitate");
    $barcode = $_POST["barcode"];
    $kos    = $_POST["kos"];
    $marca    = $_COOKIE["marca"];
    $operation = $_COOKIE["operation"];

    if (substr($barcode,0,1)=="^") {

    $j_nou =    substr($barcode,1,strpos($barcode, "|")-1);

    $parts = explode('|',$barcode);

    $of_nou = $parts[1];
    $cantitate_nou = $parts[2];
    $serie_nou = $parts[3];
    $adauga="INSERT INTO master (marca, operation,j,of,cantitate,serie,kos)
    VALUES
    ('$marca','$operation','$j_nou','$of_nou','$cantitate_nou','$serie_nou','$kos')";

    mysql_query($adauga);

    }

    header('Location: /eficacitate/scan.php');
    ob_flush();
    ?>
```

Comment: ID's need to be unique, so that might be the cause of your problem.

Comment: What IDs are you talking about? The InputID has no influence, and "my_popup" is only used once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give this a try:

```
<form action="barcode.php" method="post" class="pure-form" style="width:100%">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Scaneaza o fisa noua de <?php echo $operation; ?>:</legend>
    <input type="text" name="barcode" autofocus id="InputID" placeholder="Codul de bare" style="width:100%;font-size:2em">
    <button id='barcodeButton' style="width:0;visibility:hidden;" type="submit" onclick="show_popup('my_popup'); return false;"></button>
    <div id="my_popup" style="display:none;border:3px dotted gray;padding:.3em;background-color:white;position:absolute;width:80%;height:20%;margin:-50px 50px 0 50px;">
        <legend>Introdu numarul de KO-uri:</legend>
        <input type="text" name="kos" autofocus id="InputID" placeholder="KO-uri" style="width:100%;font-size:2em">
        <button id='kosButton' type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary" style="/*width:0;visibility:hidden;*/" onclick="hide_popup('my_popup'); return true;">Trimite</button>
    </div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function FocusOnInput() { document.getElementById("InputID").focus(); }
    document.onkeydown = function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == '13') { 
            barcodeButton = document.getElementById('barcodeButton');
            kosButton = document.getElementById('kosButton');

            if (document.getElementById('my_popup').style.display == 'none') {
                barcodeButton.click();
                show_popup('my_popup');
            } else {
                kosButton.click();
                hide_popup('my_popup');
            }
        }
    }

    function show_popup(id) {
        if (document.getElementById){
            obj = document.getElementById(id);
            if (obj.style.display == "none") {
                obj.style.display = "";
            }
        }
    }

    function hide_popup(id){
        if (document.getElementById){
            obj = document.getElementById(id);
            if (obj.style.display == ""){
                obj.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
```

Let me know if this solves what you are trying to achive.  Just out of curiosity, why aren't you using jQuery here?

Comment: Thanks a bunch, buddy! That did the trick!
I always had the impression jQuery is heavy, and I need this app to be lightweight. It will be used in a manufacturing area, on a bunch of tablets all connected via WiFi... the amount of code and requests should be minimum.